# Not-rectangular arrays in Common Lisp? (General question for didactical purposes.)

Tags: multidimensional-array, common-lisp

Simply for the sake of completeness I would like to know, whether there is a way to define "jagged" or "ragged arrays" in Common Lisp like it is described for Java e.g. here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jagged-array-in-java/

Along with this question comes the second question, what is the advantage of such a definition of multidimensional arrays? More efficient memory allocation? Or is the idea of a "jagged array" itself problematic - at least in the Common Lisp context?

Until now, I only could find descriptions of the regular way of defining rectangular multidimensional arrays - or I overlooked the information I was searching for.

At this moment, I would imagine that in Common Lisp one would fill the not needed places with NIL or 0 or something like that in a regular multidimensional array, if the replication of such an asymmetric data field seems to be useful. ... Or I would manage three vectors of different length maybe by trying to define a custom structure with them.

If these are stupid ideas, is there any other way? Or is a "ragged array" in Java simply a nested vector with elements of different size in general - and a multidimensional array in Common Lisp also simply a nested vector with elements of equal size that comes along with some helpful abstractions for managing that regular structure?

I thank you very much for your response.

Comment: Arrays exist in contiguous memory; classic jagged arrays (e.g., in C) are just arrays of pointers to memory for each row. This gives flexibility and may conserve memory, but is bad for performance since the rows of the jagged array may be spread out in memory. You could create a custom data structure with one vector to store the size of each row, and one vector to hold all of the elements of the array, but this may be troublesome if row sizes need to change.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and making me find this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jagged-array-or-array-of-arrays-in-c-with-examples/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since they are vectors of vectors they are easy to define. Example:

getter

```
(defun jref (jarray i j)
  (aref (aref jarray i) j))
```

setter

```
(defun (setf jref) (new-value jarray i j)
  (setf (aref (aref jarray i) j) new-value))
```

Make such an array: `(make-jarray '(3 (5 6 2))`

```
(defun make-jarray (dimensions &key (initial-element 0))
  (make-array
   (first dimensions)
   :initial-contents (loop for d in (second dimensions)
                           collect (make-array
                                    d
                                    :initial-element initial-element))))
```

Example:

```
CL-USER > (let ((ja1 (make-jarray '(4 (3 2 4 5)))))
            (setf (jref ja1 0 1) 'hello)
            (setf (jref ja1 3 4) 'world)
            (incf (jref ja1 2 0) 42)
            (values ja1
                    (jref ja1 2 0)))

#(#(0 HELLO 0) #(0 0) #(42 0 0 0) #(0 0 0 0 WORLD))
42
```